# Installed curl but libcurl wont update

Tags: ubuntu, curl, ubuntu-12.04, libcurl

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. I just updated the default CURL from 7.22 to 7.28 from source code.

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.28.0.tar.gz
./configure
make
make install
```

However, `libcurl` wont update.
When I try

```
curl --version
curl 7.28.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0
```

How to update `libcurl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I have to uninstall `libcurl` by using `sudo apt-get remove libcurl`.

Comment: I also had the same problem. Had to `sudo apt-get remove libcurl.`  and then reinstall what is needed, e.g., `curl`

Answer (score 9):

A default install like that will put the newly built libcurl in the `/usr/local/lib` directory. Your run-time linker will look for libcurl in its configured path and it probably finds your old libcurl dir first in `/usr/lib`.

You may need to edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` or change the setup otherwise so that the linker won't prefer the old one.

A more brutal way is of course to uninstall the distro version with `apt-get remove`.

And btw: 7.28.0 is also a very old version.

Comment: And what about Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04, I had to edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and add the following at the top of it.

`/usr/local/bin`

Then executed

`$ldconfig`

I am not sure what that means, but it works. Happy to hear reasons in comment or even an edit.

Thank you!